# How can I consolidate three functions into one function in order to carry out same functionality?

Tags: javascript, function, debugging

I have code that detects what the file type is (upon user upload) successfully if this function was separated into three separate functions (one for 2 for photos and 1 for video upload).  On my `<input/>` tags I have `onchange="fileValidation()"` on each respective input.  I'm trying to consolidate this into one function so that it carries out the aforementioned successful functionality when it was separated into three functions.

I'm using vanilla JS.  Everything's on a single page.  My guess is that it simply won't work correctly if three separate input tags have the same `fileValidation()` function.  In other words - If someone wants to do a video upload, then the other two `<input/>` tags might get confused... but I could be wrong?

How can I combine all these `if()`s inside one function so I can get this working again the way it would if separated into three functions?  Code below for reference.

```
function fileValidation() {
const realFileBtn = document.getElementById("real-file");
const realFileW9 = document.getElementById("real-file-w9");
const realFileVideo = document.getElementById("real-file-video");

let filePathWinnerPhoto = realFileBtn.value;
let filePathW9 = realFileW9.value;
let filePathVideo = realFileVideo.value;

// Allowing file type
let allowedExtensionsWinnerPhoto = /(\.jpg|\.png|\.HEIC|\.JPEG|\.pdf)$/i;
let allowedExtensionsW9 = /(\.jpg|\.png|\.HEIC|\.JPEG|\.pdf)$/i;
let allowedExtensionsVideo = /(\.mp4|\.mov)$/i;

if (!allowedExtensionsWinnerPhoto.exec(filePathWinnerPhoto)) {
    alert('Invalid file type');
    realFileBtn.value = '';
    return false;
} else {
    console.log("file accepted");
    fileAcceptedFlag = true;
}

if (!allowedExtensionsW9.exec(filePathW9)) {
    alert('Invalid file type');
    realFileW9.value = '';
    return false;
} else {
    console.log("file accepted");
    fileAcceptedW9Flag = true;
}

if (!allowedExtensionsVideo.exec(filePathVideo)) {
    alert('Invalid file type');
    realFileVideo.value = '';
    return false;
} else {
    console.log("file accepted");
    fileAcceptedVideoFlag = true;
}

return fileAcceptedFlag || fileAcceptedW9Flag || fileAcceptedVideoFlag;
```

Comment: There's not really a point in moving all three different codes into the same function.

Answer (score 0):

The below updates include an errors variable to hold the errors and returning only once at the end and alerting the errors if they exist. For testing I entered in values for the file names and commented out resetting of the input values.

```js
function fileValidation() {
const realFileBtn = document.getElementById("real-file");
const realFileW9 = document.getElementById("real-file-w9");
const realFileVideo = document.getElementById("real-file-video");

let filePathWinnerPhoto = "test.jp1g";
let filePathW9 = "test.jpxg";
let filePathVideo = "test.mov";

let imgreg = /(\.jpg|\.png|\.HEIC|\.JPEG|\.pdf)$/i;
let videoreg = /(\.mp4|\.mov)$/i;
let errors = [];

if(!imgreg.exec(filePathWinnerPhoto)){
   errors.push("Winner Photo is not valid");
   //realFileBtn.value = "";
}

if(!imgreg.exec(filePathW9)){
   errors.push("W9 Photo is not valid");
   //realFileW9.value = "";
}

if(!videoreg.exec(filePathVideo)){
   errors.push("Video is not valid");
   //realFileVideo.value = "";
}

if(errors.length > 0){
alert(errors.join("\n"));
}
return (errors.length == 0);
}
 fileValidation();
```